# Django URLs management

Tags: django

I'm a full beginner on Django. Therefore, I'm sorry if my question is not making so much sense.

I'm studying [Django tutorial - step 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-1). I installed properly Django and created my first Django project named 'vanilla'. The `urls.py` script of the vanilla project is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I start Django with this 'vanilla' project and start the development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I correctly see the start page (with a rocket).

In a second project that I named 'djtutorial', I created as requested in [Django tutorial - step 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-1) a 'polls' app. As requested, I modified `urls.py` file in `djtutorial\polls` which now has following content:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

If I start the server the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` is working properly. However, if I launch the root url of the site (i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`), I now have a 404 error.

**Why is the 'root url' of the site now hidden?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't any root URL at all. Main page informing you that your project is created properly shows up only if you don't have any view of your own added to `urlpatterns`. When you create any page, this welcome page stops showing up and that is expected.

If you want to show your own page on root of your website, use this in your urlpatterns:

```
    path('', >>VIEW OR INCLUDE HERE<<),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say that *you have not configured any URLs*, this is true. However, even in the 'vanilla' case, `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]` is defined by default by Django.

Comment: Yes, but django detects that it is default and ignores it.

Comment: Ok understand! Thanks again.